# Display Tag Customization

Tags: html, css, jsp, displaytag

How to hide the page banner message coming from the displaytag at the bottom after the records are getting displayed in pagination. Also how to customize this message as shown here http://demo.displaytag.org/displaytag-examples-1.2/example-paging.jsp

Comment: whether you want to find how many items found or how to display the total strip.

Comment: No, how to customize the css associated with the message or the strip. please see the page which I have mentioned

Comment: if you have mozilla firefox, you can easily find this by inspecting that element. Just right click on it and click on inspect element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override setting `paging.banner.placement`. Ways to do this and values for all configuration options are listed at http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/configuration.html